# Destructuring assignment with private properties at class results in "never used"

Tags: typescript, typescript2.2

I'm declaring two private, static and read—only properties in a class body. At the class methods, I'm not trying to get the properties by using indexing expressions in the class object, I'm using destructuring assignment in a `const` declaration.

There's no problem with the destructuring assignment, but if I don't try to index my class to get these private properties, TypeScript gives me the following warnings:

> 'PROGRESS_BAR_WIDTH' is declared but never used.
>
> 'PROGRESS_BAR_HEIGHT' is declared but never used.

I've created an issue at the TypeScript GitHub repository, but got no help yet.

A note: when these properties aren't private (public), these warning fade in. I use these private-static (and read—only) properties in the `init` method, which isn't static.

Here's my code:

```
import {PICTURES} from './../data/pictures';
import {WAVES} from './../data/waves';
import {GlobalBounds} from './../constants/global-bounds';

const stuffs = [];

export class PreloaderContainer extends createjs.Container
{
    private static readonly PROGRESS_BAR_WIDTH:number = 183;

    private static readonly PROGRESS_BAR_HEIGHT:number = 6;

    private progressBar: createjs.Shape;

    private progressWrapper: createjs.Shape;

    public constructor ()
    {
        super();
        this.init();
    }

    private init () : void
    {
        const {PROGRESS_BAR_WIDTH, PROGRESS_BAR_HEIGHT} = PreloaderContainer;

        const progressWrapper = new createjs.Shape;
        const progressBar = new createjs.Shape;

        progressWrapper.graphics

            .setStrokeStyle(1)

            .beginStroke('#646464')

            .drawRect(0, 0, PROGRESS_BAR_WIDTH,
                            PROGRESS_BAR_HEIGHT);

        progressWrapper.x =
            progressBar.x = (GlobalBounds.WIDTH / 2) - (PROGRESS_BAR_WIDTH / 2);

        progressWrapper.y =
            progressBar.y = 300;

        progressBar.graphics

            .beginFill('#646464')

            .drawRect(0, 0, 20,
                            PROGRESS_BAR_HEIGHT);

        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        this.progressWrapper = progressWrapper;
        this.addChild(progressBar);
        this.addChild(progressWrapper);

        this.preload();
    }

    private preload () : void
    {
        let loadedFiles:number = 0;

        //const len:number = stuffs.length;
        const queue = new createjs.LoadQueue;

        queue.addEventListener('complete', function () : void
        {}, false);

        queue.addEventListener('fileload', function (evt) : void
        {
            ++loadedFiles;

            const item = evt.item;
            const id = (<any> stuffs.filter(obj => obj === item)[0]).id;
            const result = evt.result;

            (result instanceof Audio ?
                WAVES :
                PICTURES
            )[id] = result;
        }, false);

        queue.loadManifest(stuffs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you using the static member?

Comment: @torazaburo At the `init` method (which is private).

Comment: Oh! It was tagged as a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found explanations for this. For now the appropriate solution I've found is to avoid the `private` access modifier for `PROGRESS_BAR_WIDTH` and `PROGRESS_BAR_HEIGHT` members, that is, let them be public.